Reporting a typo in ubuntu 23.10.1 installation
Typo: Poku -> Pokud
This typo is in czech installation

FYI:  This is a user support site, not a bug tracking/reporting site. Reports need to be given the developers, not end-users that use these support sites.

It's a bit late to fix 23.10 translations. Check if the problem still exists in pre-release 24.04. It can perhaps still be fixed there.
